# MySQL timezone not in sync with system

Tags: php, mysql, date, ubuntu, timezone

**PHP timezone:**

date.timezone   Europe/Helsinki Europe/Helsinki

**MySQL timezone:**

@@global.time_zone:
SYSTEM
@@session.time_zone:
SYSTEM

**MySQL NOW();**

2015-06-22 10:22:28

**Ubuntu "date":**

Mon Jun 22 11:22:28 EEST 2015

---

I would like to have MySQL time sync with the system time, which is the correct time. Apparently the problem is, that MySQL does not recognize summertime which means that time should be +1 hour to normal time.

How to switch MySQL time to summertime just like the system does, without changing the timezone?